# Accessing VM host without ssh

Tags: linux, redhat, virtual-machines

**Issue:**
A RHEL VM host is not accessible via ssh.

**Root cause of the issue:**
Accidentally a shared library zlib is removed from the rpm package of the machine. Making it to fail all needed commands such as yum, ssh, scp, wget and rpm with the following error.

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Additional detail:**
The missing library is copied from another server to a user home directory (myuser) in the machine: /home/(myuser)/usr/{lib, lib64, share}/*

Does copying these directories to  /usr/{lib, lib64, share}/*, which require administrator (root) privilege, fix the issue?

Currently, the machine cannot be connected via ssh.

Is there a way to get into the box without using ssh?

Comment: Boot into a rescue system and fix this from there.

Comment: Use the server (remote) console.

Comment: Or you can mount the volume into another running linux and fix it there. Similar to what @Sven suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Sven's comment, booting into a rescue system and then copying the library fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Connect to the machine via the console from the hypervisor,

You can log in with the root credentials, and do all you need to be able to do.